# sqlsrv_connect has no result at all

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I'm new to php, trying to connect to mssql server 2012 database using sqlsrv.
The following code:

```
<?php   
$server = 'ip address';
echo 'I\'m in<br />';   
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"name", "UID"=>"user", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $server, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}    
?>
```

results in nothing - I have no idea what's going on but I don't get "Connection established" or "Connection could not be established." it just seems to die or something like that.
Using php 5.2 (didn't try other versions).
Any suggestions?

Comment: As a first thing, if you are new you should use the newest versions of PHP (5.6) and [sqlsrv extension](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.installation.php) (3.2). **Second step should be activating error  reporting.** There could be two main troubles with SQLSRV. You have to enable sqlsrv extension and install microsoft odbc driver.

Comment: when I do that my apache won't start, saying there is some error loading php5apache2_2.dll, though it is present in php directory

Comment: well, changing php helped after all, only had to change to 5.3 to make apache not to crash, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was stated in comment for my actual question - it had to do something with my php version, changing it to a later one (not latest though) worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `server name` in, delete the `echo`, delete everything in the `connectionInfo array` besides `"Database"=>"yourdbname"` . Now try, if it doesn't work I'll give you a link to somewhere. Also, when I say delete the `echo` I mean the one on the second line..

Comment: did nothing, also I'm trying to connect to mssql server 2012 if that's needed

Comment: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72XCFF4YiOw` is that what you're trying to connect to? if so, hope that tut helps you out.